# Databricks Print Statement Mismatched Input

Tags: sql, databricks

I am new to Databricks and am trying to print the following statement:

```
print("I need to go to the pool.")
```

I have to create a new cmd through the Explore the Quickstart Tutorial and print the statement in the new cmd, but I keep receiving the error listed below when I attempt to do it. How do I print the statement without receiving an error.

Error in SQL statement: ParseException:

> mismatched input '#' expecting {'(', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'OPTIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 1, pos 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute the Python code in the SQL cell (it looks like that you have SQL as default language for the notebook).  You can either change the default language (click on `SQL` near the notebook name), or you can prefix your statement with `%python` to switch language only for specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need parenthesis

```
print "I need to go to the pool."
```

Comment: I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: ok then you don't need parenthesis , try my updated answer